# Returning 0 if resullt is None to avoid 'NoneType' and 'decimal.Decimal'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add return 0 in case the final result of an equation is None to get away from:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'decimal.Decimal'`
but it is not working for me.

The reason for this is that the no. of sold count can be zero so it returns Type Error.

Here is the function:

```
    def designer_total_discount_price(self):
        total_sold_discount = self.count_sold * self.discount_price
        return 0 if total_sold_discount is None else total_sold_discount

    def designer_total_price(self):
        total_sold_regular = self.count_sold * self.price
        return 0 if total_sold_regular is None else total_sold_regular

    def designer_total(self):
        if self.discount_price:
            return self.designer_total_discount_price()
        return self.designer_total_price()

    def get_designer_final(self):
        return self.designer_total() * self.designer_profit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that `self.count_sold` is `None`. You can't multiply a number with `None`. Other than making sure `self.count_sold` is always `None` you could add this method:

```py
    def get_count_sold(self):
        return 0 if self.count_sold is None else self.count_sold
```

And then you would swap out `self.count_sold` with `self.get_count_sold()`. You can also remove the if statement in the return statement. So something like this:

```py
    def designer_total_discount_price(self):
        return self.get_count_sold() * self.discount_price

    def designer_total_price(self):
        return self.get_count_sold() * self.price
```

This is my first answer on Stack Overflow. I hope it helped! :)